# Postgres "Cannot take logarithm of zero" Error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use

```
ln(session_length) - avg(ln(session_length)) OVER (PARTITION BY device_platform) / nullif(stddev(ln(session_length)) OVER (PARTITION BY device_platform), 0) AS ln_std
```

for removing outliers with SQL. I have used the function with Redshift before and I did not get any error but when I use this with Postgres I get

```
[2201E] ERROR: cannot take logarithm of zero
```

The error comes when I added where clause with `ln_std <= 1.67` otherwise there is no error.
Can someone point me if I miss something.

My code is:

```
SELECT
  user_id
, event_date
, device_platform
, marketing_user
, session_length
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      user_id
    , date(event_time) AS event_date
    , device_platform
    , marketing_user AS marketing_user
    , session_length
      --! Normalisation: Using a logarithmic scale (ln())
      --! Create the Z score for removing the outliers
    , ln(session_length) - avg(ln(session_length)) OVER (PARTITION BY device_platform) /
                                 nullif(stddev(ln(session_length)) OVER (PARTITION BY device_platform),
                                        0) AS ln_std
    FROM
      session_start
    WHERE
      date(install_time) >= '2020-01-01'
  ) filter
WHERE
  ln_std <= 1.67
```

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. Without having access to your data, we cannot tell you precisely *why* you're getting a 0, but that's what is happening.

Comment: If you are asking for a workaround: `ln(nullif(session_length,0))` would probably fix this

Answer (score 1):

There is a value less than or equal to zero in your `session_length` column, the error is describing it pretty well. Do some analysis on why this is happening and threat them accordingly.